# Woocommerce for each attribute loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

how do you output variation attributes for an woocommerce product, where each attribute is in a seperate div?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_color_attribute', 5 );
    function display_color_attribute() {
        global $product;

        if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
            $taxonomy = 'pa_color';
            echo '<span class="attribute-color">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>';
        }
    }
```

This right here output both colors on the product page seperated by a comma so for one product it could be:

```
<span class="attribute-color">Black, Brown</span>
```

What i would like is to output these two colors in two seperate div, like this:

```
<span class="attribute-color black">Black</span>
<span class="attribute-color brown">Brown</span>
```

is this doable?

Comment: What value type is returned for `$product->get_attribute($taxonomy)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.By looking your code  as well as based on [get_attribute() details](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productget_attribute/) you are actually getting a comma separated string.

2.So `explode()` it to convert to array and loop over it like below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_color_attribute', 5 );
function display_color_attribute() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_color';
        $colors = explode(',',$product->get_attribute($taxonomy));
        foreach ($colors as $color) {
            echo '<span class="attribute-color '. strtolower(trim($color)) .'">' . trim($color) . '</span>';
        }   
    }
}
```

Reference:-

[explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

[strtolower()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

[trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: @J.Doe  Glad to help you :):)

Comment: Is it possible to add this to it:

<div class="circle">
        <div style="background-color: var(--show color attribute);"></div>
        <a href="https://example.com/?attribute_pa_color=(show color attribute)"></a>
    </div>

where the "show color attribute" shows for example "brown" or another color :)?
like u just did with my div?

Comment: @J.Doe yes you can

Comment: can u help me do it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `$product->get_attribute($taxonomy);` returns an array so you would need to loop over it like below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_color_attribute', 5 );
function display_color_attribute() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_color';
        $colors = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);
        foreach ($colors as $color) {
            echo '<span class="attribute-color '. strtolower($color) .'">' . $color . '</span>';
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you dude! However it only worked with explode like the other answer suggested :)